# BIGQUERY YTD Sum not calculating properly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query result UNION' d with a calendar table and the results are as below.
I want to add a YTD calculation to it as below but the results I am expecting are not correct.

```
SELECT *,
sum(AMOUNT) over (partition by FISCAL_YEAR, GL_ACCOUNT, WORKCENTRE_CODE, UNIT_OF_MEASURE order by FISCAL_MONTH ) as YTD_AMOUNT
FROM
(SELECT * FROM QUERY 1
UNION with SELECT * FROM QUERY 2)
```

Result of above query:

| Version | WCODE | ACC | UOM | FISCAL_MONTH | FISCAL_YEAR | CALENDAR_DATE | CALENDAR_MONTH | AMOUNT | DATE_YYYYMM | YTD_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 1 | 2021 | 31/07/2020 | 202007 | 565.95 | 202007 | 565.95 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 1 | 2021 | 31/07/2020 | 202007 | 0 | 202007 | 565.95 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 2 | 2021 | 31/08/2020 | 202008 | 569.95 | 202008 | 1135.9 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 2 | 2021 | 31/08/2020 | 202008 | 0 | 202008 | 1135.9 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 3 | 2021 | 30/09/2020 | 202009 | 1190.7 | 202009 | 2326.6 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 3 | 2021 | 30/09/2020 | 202009 | 0 | 202009 | 2326.6 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 4 | 2021 | 31/10/2020 | 202010 | 664.85 | 202010 | 2991.45 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 4 | 2021 | 31/10/2020 | 202010 | 0 | 202010 | 2991.45 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 5 | 2021 | 30/11/2020 | 202011 | 606.7 | 202011 | 3598.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 5 | 2021 | 30/11/2020 | 202011 | 0 | 202011 | 3598.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 6 | 2021 | 31/12/2020 | 202012 | 826.7 | 202012 | 4424.85 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 6 | 2021 | 31/12/2020 | 202012 | 0 | 202012 | 4424.85 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 7 | 2021 | 31/01/2021 | 202101 | 871.3 | 202101 | 5296.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 7 | 2021 | 31/01/2021 | 202101 | 0 | 202101 | 5296.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 8 | 2021 | 28/02/2021 | 202102 | 847.4 | 202102 | 6143.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 8 | 2021 | 28/02/2021 | 202102 | 0 | 202102 | 6143.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 9 | 2021 | 31/03/2021 | 202103 | 1225.45 | 202103 | 7369 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 9 | 2021 | 31/03/2021 | 202103 | 0 | 202103 | 7369 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 10 | 2021 | 30/04/2021 | 202104 | 798.55 | 202104 | 8167.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 10 | 2021 | 30/04/2021 | 202104 | 0 | 202104 | 8167.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 11 | 2021 | 31/05/2021 | 202105 | 936.2 | 202105 | 9103.75 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 11 | 2021 | 31/05/2021 | 202105 | 0 | 202105 | 9103.75 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 12 | 2021 | 30/06/2021 | 202106 | 0 | 202106 | 9103.75 |

Expected Result:

| Version | WCODE | ACC | UOM | FISCAL_MONTH | FISCAL_YEAR | CALENDAR_DATE | CALENDAR_MONTH | AMOUNT | DATE_YYYYMM | YTD_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 1 | 2021 | 31/07/2020 | 202007 | 565.95 | 202007 | 565.95 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 1 | 2021 | 31/07/2020 | 202007 | 0 | 202007 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 2 | 2021 | 31/08/2020 | 202008 | 569.95 | 202008 | 1135.9 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 2 | 2021 | 31/08/2020 | 202008 | 0 | 202008 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 3 | 2021 | 30/09/2020 | 202009 | 1190.7 | 202009 | 2326.6 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 3 | 2021 | 30/09/2020 | 202009 | 0 | 202009 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 4 | 2021 | 31/10/2020 | 202010 | 664.85 | 202010 | 2991.45 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 4 | 2021 | 31/10/2020 | 202010 | 0 | 202010 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 5 | 2021 | 30/11/2020 | 202011 | 606.7 | 202011 | 3598.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 5 | 2021 | 30/11/2020 | 202011 | 0 | 202011 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 6 | 2021 | 31/12/2020 | 202012 | 826.7 | 202012 | 4424.85 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 6 | 2021 | 31/12/2020 | 202012 | 0 | 202012 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 7 | 2021 | 31/01/2021 | 202101 | 871.3 | 202101 | 5296.15 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 7 | 2021 | 31/01/2021 | 202101 | 0 | 202101 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 8 | 2021 | 28/02/2021 | 202102 | 847.4 | 202102 | 6143.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 8 | 2021 | 28/02/2021 | 202102 | 0 | 202102 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 9 | 2021 | 31/03/2021 | 202103 | 1225.45 | 202103 | 7369 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 9 | 2021 | 31/03/2021 | 202103 | 0 | 202103 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 10 | 2021 | 30/04/2021 | 202104 | 798.55 | 202104 | 8167.55 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 10 | 2021 | 30/04/2021 | 202104 | 0 | 202104 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 11 | 2021 | 31/05/2021 | 202105 | 936.2 | 202105 | 9103.75 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 11 | 2021 | 31/05/2021 | 202105 | 0 | 202105 | 0 |
| A | 333333 | 3005 | hours | 12 | 2021 | ####### | **202106 | 0 | 202106 | 9103.75** |

Ideally I would only like to add the missing month only i.e in this case '202106' and then YTD Calculated for the 12 months.

The current results in the output layer are aggregating which is incorrect.

Comment: The results certainly look like a cumulative sum which is correct.  Perhaps you should better explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want the YTD amount to be `0` when the amount is `0`.  Otherwise the calculation is correct.  That is conditional logic:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE sum(AMOUNT) over (partition by FISCAL_YEAR, GL_ACCOUNT, WORKCENTRE_CODE, UNIT_OF_MEASURE order by FISCAL_MONTH )
        END) as YTD_AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT * FROM QUERY 1
      UNION with SELECT * FROM QUERY 2
     ) t
```

Comment: The above solution will return 0 for 202106 as well which defeats the purpose. My original data set has data for 11 months, using the UNION I am trying to add the missing month '202106' using a calendar table. I am not sure if there is a way to add just the missing month so I am adding all the 12 months with an amount assigned as 0. I want the YTD calculation for the 11 months plus the missing month, if I am making sense

Comment: Is there a way to add the missing months without using the calendar table? If yes then then the YTD calculation should work seamlessly